Reference request: map to Grassmannian induced by vector bundle
During a seminar I've come across the following (universal?) property of Grassmannians

Let $S$ be a complex manifold, and let $E$ be a holomorphic sub-bundle of $\mathcal{O}_S^{N+1}$ of rank $r$. Then there is an uniquely determined holomorphic map $$f: S \longrightarrow \operatorname{Gr}(r,N+1),$$
such that $E$ is isomorphic to the pull-back $f^*\mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is the universal bundle on the Grassmannian.

First of all, is this statement true? I'm struggling to find a decent reference to verify it. I mostly found results about the differentiable case or discussions on the classifications of vector bundles via the infinite Grassmannian. What about this particular holomorphic case? Thanks in advance for every hint.

Yes that is true. Each point $s \in S$ determines an $r$-dimensional subspace $E_s \subset \mathbb C^{N+1}$, and the map $f: S \to \operatorname{Gr}(r,N+1)$ is given by $s \mapsto [E_s \subset \mathbb C^{N+1}]$. One has to check that this is a holomorphic map, which can be done on local charts, I think. Then $f^* \mathcal U$ is a subbundle of $\mathcal O_X^{N+1}$, which for each $s$ agrees with $E$, so that
$$E = f^* \mathcal U.$$
